# What does this `-n` mean? [BASH]

Tags: bash

Please take a look at this code sample:

```
MIN=10

if [ -n "$1" ]; then echo "$1"; fi
if [ -n "$2" ]; then echo "$2"; fi 
if [ -n "$3" ]; then echo "$3"; fi
if [ -n "$4" ]; then echo "$4"; fi
if [ -n "$5" ]; then echo "$5"; fi
if [ -n "$6" ]; then echo "$6"; fi
if [ -n "$7" ]; then echo "$7"; fi
if [ -n "$8" ]; then echo "$8"; fi
if [ -n "$9" ]; then echo "$9"; fi
if [ -n "${10}" ]; then echo "${10}"; fi

echo "List of arguments: "$*"" 
echo "Name of this script: "$0""
if [ $# -lt "$MIN" ]; then echo "Not enough arguments, need $MIN to run."; fi
```

For example, the terminal output of `$./new.sh q w e r t y u i o p` will be:

```
q
w
e
r
t
y
u
i
o
p
List of arguments: q w e r t y u i o p
Name of this script: ./new.sh
```

And the output of `$./new.sh q w e r t y u i o` will be:

```
q
w
e
r
t
y
u
i
o
List of arguments: q w e r t y u i o
Name of this script: ./new.sh
Not enough arguments, need 10 to run.
```

**Question**: What does the `-n` mean?

Comment: Did you check the bash manpage, or read `help test`?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals . Not surprisingly, stuff like `[` and `-n` are horrible to search for.

Comment: @ilkkachu Certainly it is for total beginners like me.

Comment: If you came here wondering what `bash -n myscript` does, it does a [syntax check](https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/15685/checking-the-syntax-of-a-script-with---n-) on the script instead of running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is another name for the `test` builtin, see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals), also [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

That sequence of `if` statements would probably be better off as a loop. In Bash we could use indirect expansion:

```
for ((i=1 ; i <= 10 ; i++)) ; do 
    if [ -n "${!i}" ] ; then 
        echo "${!i}"
    fi
done
```

The more common idiom would probably be to use `shift` on every iteration, but it destroys the argument list.

Also, quoting: here `$0` is outside the quotes. In most cases its more useful to keep all variable expansions within quotes, unless you explicitly want [word-splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and filename expansion.

```
echo "Name of this script: "$0""
```

So, rather write:

```
echo "Name of this script: $0"
```

Comment: You can use `shift` inside a function and not affect the caller's argument list, though using a function just for that is obviously a bit hackish.